# Is using scaffolding in cakephp good practice?

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP. I have learnt about the concept of scaffolding in it, it seems to be good concept. But my question is that **Is it a good practice to use scaffolding for production level app development** as official CakePHP documentation says that *It isn’t meant to be completely flexible, it’s meant as a temporary way to get up and going.*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says that it's not flexible enough. However it still works, also when debug level is 0.

Scaffolding is Automatic CRUD creation. cakephp generates CRUD when you bake.

Scaffold has the advantage that it's meant for early stage of development.

For more read

http://www.indywebshop.com/bestpractices/2007/06/13/early-impressions-of-cakephp/

but i suggest not to use it because at any stage you will need to write your own code.
But for application which are not frequently get changed its really helps.

Comment: yah we can...till now i didn't use it because most often we need to use custom code...

Comment: With the powerful baking capabilities you got these days with cakephp there is no need to use scaffolding anymore. Just make your own custom bake templates and voila: You got the perfect CRUD views in no time.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say it is useful for MVP if you want to hack up a web app fast.

But a no no if you want production grade end product